# How to set the templete design for mailers in ruby on rails app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html-email

I want to design a template for mailers in ruby on rails app. The mailers delivered are missing styling. I tried to add inline css but some css properties are missing.

Comment: Could you paste code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [Roadie](https://github.com/Mange/roadie) can solve your problem. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/312-sending-html-email?view=asciicast) is a railscast for it as well.